# Rocking a bottle back and forth - What physics systems are at work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I want to understand the physics that occur during the attempt at tipping over a bottle / rocking a bottle back and forth.

I am expecting that:

1. when the finger pushes the bottle for a tiny moment, it applies a force (**F1**). It makes sense that the bottle will tip in that direction. I'll call this vector **V1**.
2. after a period, the bottle will stop moving in that direction (**V1**), and will start to move back towards its starting position (**-V1**) if the bottle did not reach its tipping point.
3. after it reaches its starting position, it would pass that starting position momentarily in **-V1**  and then it might rock back and forth as the energy supplied by that force transfers to other systems and the bottle comes back to a resting state.

[image]

I am coding this very system for a game. I have been confused at what I may be missing. I see that this may be quite a variation of things at play here so need a guiding hand as to how one should go about thinking about what systems are involved in the rocking back and forth of a bottle that was pushed. These are the things I've been mulling over / trying to code / considering noteworthy.

1. Centre of mass
2. Tipping point
3. Momentum
4. Impulse
5. Moment of inertia?

The actual problem I am having is that I apply **F1** as a vector **V1** and I work out the angle (theta) to angle my bottle with atan(V1/h):

[image]

But this needs to happen over time?
So I used Momentum **(p = mg*V1)** so that I could use Impulse (**p * Time elapsed since force was applied**) and when the bottle gets to its full velocity, I don't know what force is acting against it. Why does the bottle rock backwards and then why does it go slightly back over the starting position
(rocking back and forth) before finally coming to its starting position. Is this mg tugging on it or is this more of an energy problem?

**TL;DR**

What are the kinds of physics systems I need to be aware of when simulating a person rocking a bottle back and forth with a single push from a finger.

Comment: *I am coding this very system for a game.* A commercial one?

Comment: _ why does it go slightly back over the starting position (rocking back and forth) before finally coming to its starting position._ The bottle should have some angular momentum, that make it continue to move. It takes time for it to stop.

Comment: Hint: In the picture, you the bottle going inside the horizontal surface. Do you think this is realistic? Where _is_ the contact point location?

Comment: "angular momentum/time to stop" - ahh!!! I think I can YouTube some details for that. Thank you!!!

Comment: "going inside horizontal" - haha, well spotted... I wanted to make the equation more simple to begin with and then add the width of the bottle into it... Was that not a good idea. Woops?

Comment: "a commercial one" - it's a personal project to Inspire me to learn physics. :-) - I'm 31... It had to happen at some point haha.

Comment: If you want to make a computer game, a more efficient method of getting a realistic effect is to make a video of a bottle being rocked, and then try to imitate its motion in your game. If you want to learn physics, a more efficient method is to study from a textbook or online tutorial.

Comment: @sammygerbil ya. i know rite. How silly of me to not think of that first (says the 31 year old who didn't even know what amplitude means).

Answer (score 0):

- **Warning**: This may be full of "Fayyyk neeews". Please don't trust anything in this answer.
- **Warning 2**: No, really. Don't.

## Summary:

I ended up using a pendulum or a "Simple pendulum" to be more precise. I thought this best estimated my single point of axis for the bottle o' hooch. I've no idea, but it's the best I've got so far...

## Sources of help:

- Understanding the motion of a pendulum: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPa5IgLgDyQ&t=41s
- Understanding energy loss: https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/pendulum-lab/latest/pendulum-lab_en.html
- and a million other sites I googled. (fingers start to bleed)

## Equations:

### Time period equation

```
T = 2π * sqrt(L / g)
```

- `2 * π` is equal to 360 (If you convert from radians into degrees. Interesting right? Yup, I didn't know that. cool huh)
- `L / g` gave me this intuition, I'm not sure if it's right:

[image]

- Yeah, one thing to note... "All simple pendulums should have the same period regardless of their initial angle" - Weird right? But, oh well, who am I to argue (I love physics haha, it's so quirky) - source: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/16-4-the-simple-pendulum/

Regardless, that's the equation and so in terms of code per frame, I did this:

```
timePeriod: float = (
    2 * math.pi * math.sqrt( length / gravitationalAcceleration )
)
```

And now I needed the initial amount of energy in my system. I found this equation, no idea if it's correct but:

### Energy at all points apart from when pendulum at 90 degrees or equilibrium (at rest) equation

So, apparently: *"Gravitational potential energy can be calculated by multiplying the mass, the acceleration due to gravity, and the height change. Once the mass is let go, it starts to swing. Kinetic energy (KE) is the energy of motion, and is the product of one-half the mass, and the square of the velocity (v) in m/s."*

I struggled with an intuition on this but here's my code I made from it which clearly just completely avoided anything mentioned in the above sentence... Help meee:

```
# startingAmplitude is the starting angle of your pendulum.
# I know right? Just say that from the start? :)
startingEnergy: float = (
    gravitationalAcceleration * length * ( 1 - math.cos( startingAmplitude ) )
)
```

## Making the pendulum do its thing:

Looking good:

- We know how long it takes for one full swing of the pendulum
- We know how much energy is in the system at the start
- The above two statements may be incorrect, but who am I to know? :D

So now for the **loop of my pendulum** to make it go back and forth. I think I got this equation from the aforementioned video. I can't quite remember, but it seems to make sense as I am now running my angle in relation to how much time has been, and how much time it takes for an entire swing of the pendulum (in relationship to a circle... the 2 * pi bit):

```
theta: float = startingAmplitude * math.cos(
    ( ( 2 * math.pi ) / timePeriod ) * elapsedTime
)
# Note: Might need to be careful of radians and degrees
```

**Now for the friction** to come into play... Well, I just multiplied the theta generated in the frame in question, by the remaining energy of the system as a percentage, which decremented per cycle using an arbitrary "friction" value. Ugly right?

```
percentageEnergy: float = energyLeft / startingEnergy
coordinate: Coordinate = Coordinate(theta * percentageEnergy, elapsedTime)
currentEnergy -= friction
```

## Success. Maybe? Not sure... Seems to look right-ish?:

And that's all folks. This might all be entirely wrong, but I tried. This is the graph I made:

[image]

I really hope someone corrects all of my mistakes here, but if not, atleast it roughly looks like a pendulum and **I can apply this to my problem of a bottle tipping back and forth**... Because, if the initial gravitational potential energy = 0, for example, the bottle is standing still... then I can simply add the energy with the push of my finger and use the same equations to decrease its value over time. (I hope).

Fin.

Comment: Side note, this is amazing and realy helps to visualise the kinds of forces acting on an object! http://www.algodoo.com/